# Why am I receiving a null error exception when I want to add from a list?

Tags: c#, list

I am reading from a list the co-ordinates of a piece of armour. When it finds that specific armour, its supposed to take that armour object, and add it to another list. Yet I receive a null object error (object reference not set to an instance of an object)?

```
foreach (Armour item in armousOnMap)
        {
            if (item.Row == _yPosition && item.Column == _xPosition)
            {                    
                armourInventory.Add((Armour)item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure `armourInventory` is initialized as `new List<Armour>`?

Comment: what is armourInventory and how was it instantiated?

Comment: And which line is failing? Basically, *something* is null - either `item`, or `armousOnMap`, or `armourInventory`. Beyond that, we can't help you with so little information. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: perhaps its a null information exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all coordinates populated? i.e. not nulls?

```
var armourInventory = new List<Armour>();

foreach (Armour item in armousOnMap)
{
    if ((item.Row != null && item.Row == _yPosition) && (item.Column != null && item.Column == _xPosition))
    {                    
        armourInventory.Add((Armour)item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize list first, and the add items into it.

```
var armourInventory = new List<Armour>();
```

Add this line when you are making your list.

```
var armourInventory = new List<Armour>();
foreach (Armour item in armousOnMap)
{
    if (item.Row == _yPosition && item.Column == _xPosition)
    {                    
        armourInventory.Add((Armour)item);
    }
}
```